A strongly continuous semigroup with 3rd derivative as generator?
Stochastic processes offer good examples of C0-semigroups and their infinitesimal generators contain one or more of these components

$r \cdot u()$ equivalent to discounting in finance
$\mu \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$: drift or space translation
$\sigma^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$: diffusion or space averaging
$\alpha ( u(x) - u(x - k) )$: a jump of size $k$

I wonder which other operations on $u$ are legal and what they mean.
For instance, are higher order (3+) derivatives allowed? And if so, what physical process are they related to?
EDIT: in the same way as the heat equation does not affect linear functions (they have no convexity), the hypothetical 3rd derivative semigroup, would only affect things with a 3rd derivative.
So, any initial condition which is linear or quadratic would pass through it unchanged, but something with a 3rd derivative (e.g. $f(x)=x^3$) would get more value since it has a 3rd derivative.
In a way some sort of Jensen inequality for 3rd derivatives.
The same for 4 and above.
Do these have any physical meaning or application?
